# WPF scroll bar on wrap panel grayed out

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I have read numerous related topics on this but can't find a solution.  In WPF I am trying to place a vertical scroll bar on a wrap panel.  I am dynamically building the wrap panel and it has labels and textboxes.  Here is my wrap panel wrapped in a scroll viewer...

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True" IsEnabled="True" AllowDrop="True">
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="wpAddAttribute" Width="1129" IsEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"></WrapPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

Here is the C# code to dynamically build each row...

```
private void AddAttribute(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Attribute Name", Name = "lbNewTestAttributeNameLabel" });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new TextBox { Height = 26, Name = "tbNewTestAttributeName", Width = 75 });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Attribute Value", Name = "lbNewTestAttributeValueLabel" });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new TextBox { Height = 26, Name = "tbNewTestAttributeValue", Width = 55 });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Attribute Units", Name = "lbNewTestAttributeUnitsLabel" });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new TextBox { Height = 26, Name = "tbNewTestAttributeUnits", Width = 55 });

            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Attribute Minimum Value", Name = "lbNewTestAttributeMinValueLabel" });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new TextBox { Height = 26, Name = "tbNewTestAttributeMinValue", Width = 55 });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Attribute Maximum Value", Name = "lbNewTestAttributeMaxValueLabel" });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new TextBox { Height = 26, Name = "tbNewTestAttributeMaxValue", Width = 55 });

            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Stepping Minimum Value", Name = "lbNewTestSteppingMinValueLabel" });
            wpAddAttribute.Children.Add(new TextBox { Height = 26, Name = "tbNewTestAttributeMinValue", Width = 55 });
                        }
```

I do see a vertical scroll bar on the right side of the screen but it is always grayed out, even when I exceed the space I'm in.  Any ideas of how to get the scrolling on/not grayed out?

Here is my wrap panel with the parent border container...

```
 <Border Name="bdAddTestArea" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10"  Margin="10" Width="1130" Height="330" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <StackPanel ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0">Add a Test</TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="New Test Name:"></Label>
                        <TextBox Name="tbNewTestName" Width="75"></TextBox>
                        <Label Content="Test Estimate (in seconds):"></Label>
                        <TextBox Name="tbTestEstimate" Width="75"></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True" IsEnabled="True" AllowDrop="True">
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="wpAddAttribute" Width="1129" IsEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"></WrapPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Visibility="Visible" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Add an Attribute" Click="AddAttribute" Width="96" Margin="5 5 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Button>
                <Button Content="Save Test" Click="SaveTest" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5 5 0 0"></Button>
                <Button Content="Return To Test Selection" Click="ReturnToSelectionPanel" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5 5 0 0"></Button>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
```

Comment: Did you try to specify a `Height` for the ScrollViewer or its parent container? What is the parent container? Please provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue when asking a question.

Comment: I tried to post the parent container but its limiting me on size.  It does have a height=330.  Is that my issue?  Here is the code for the parent container...<Border Name="bdAddTestArea" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10"  Margin="10" Width="1130" Height="330" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

Comment: Does the total width of all elements really exceed 1130 so there is any wrapping?

Comment: It does when the user adds enough lines.  When I do that it just goes beyond the border and you don't see the lines that are pushed passed the bottom of the border, which is why I need the scrolling to work.

Comment: Please provide a minimal but reproducible sample of your issue including the Border and the add functionality then.

Comment: See above for the parent container.  It was too big to add here in the comments but it did let me add it as an edit to my original post.  The add code is up there too.  Let me know if that is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why the orientation of wrap panel is Horizontal if you want to implement it vertically, change orientation to Vertical. It is working fine here then.

Comment: I have the wrap panel orientation as horizontal so the fields I dynamically load in the code behind will load on the same row.  Changing this to vertical will load these fields on separate rows.